# SSRS remove bar graph inner varibles

Tags: reporting-services, label

I have a bar chart in SSRS that shows 2 y-axis variables showing. How do I remove the inner variables?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the Chart's Axis Interval set to $2000. This forces the axis to show each $2000 interval.

Since there's not enough room to put the in a single column, the chart **offsets** the axis labels to make them fit.

You can either make your labels smaller and disable the **Labels can be offset** to try to make the all fit in a single column.

Or you can set the Interval to **Auto**. This *usually* works OK.

[image]

[image]